# Getting two models to show on a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im making a website that involves creating a login system.  For the sign in and register I want to use models.  when I go to create my second model it just displays what is on the first one.
This Is an example of what it looks like.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

```
    <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>The First Model</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="myRegisterBtn">Register</button>
<div id="myRegister" class="register">
  <div class="register-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Second Model</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

  // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myRegister');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myRegisterBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }`enter code here`
}
```

and This is my CSS

```
    /* --------------- Code for model ---------*/
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px
    font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.register{
      display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */

}
.register-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}
```

Comment: Do you want to display a second modal when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of you modal are save in a var called `modal`, in these lines:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal = document.getElementById('myRegister');
```

Since all you code has been ran before you start clicking on buttons, the `modal` var refers to the second modal you have, so everytime one of your `onclick` event fires, it is runned on the second modal.

I suggest you simply change the names of the 2 variables, or better refer to them in you event, this way:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myRegister');
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now the second model wont close.  And the close button on the fist one wont work.

Comment: you get the close button this way `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];`, but since there is 2 buttons close (one for each modal), the onclick event is only on one of the modal close button and the other one won't work.